how to copy/paste blocks in wagtail(wagtail into existing django project)
i try to understand requirements and know the possible methods and the wagtail project is using wagtail-modeltranslation, here is the requirements:
"Main purpose of this is to speed up making new pages, and the translation from EN to NL.
Now, when we make a nice series of blocks in EN, we need to rebuild them all for the NL version, which is annoying. If we can copy and paste the blocks from the EN version into the NL version, we only need to replace the actual texts, not all the images, sliders, caroussels, etc etc."
i want to understand and do solution like how to copy blocks from EN version to NL version??? and how should handle the problem(with clear steps).
i hope sbd will solve my dream!!!

I recommend wagtail-localize for this rather than model-translation. Wagtail-localize will copy your streamfields and set up the translation fields for each translatable block. Might be a bit of work to migrate if you already have a running project, otherwise easy to set up.

i know wagtail-localize is better but it is mandatory to me to work with wagtail-modeltranslation.
